# TypeError: Attempted to wrap getRepository which is already wrapped

Tags: javascript, typescript, sinon

I need to wrap a method multiple time with sinon to be able to return different objects based on the argument. How would I do this?

The controller I want to test looks something like this:

```js
const servicePackagesOfferingRepository = Salesforce.getRepository(ServicePackageOffering);
const servicePackageOffering = await servicePackagesOfferingRepository.findOneById(model.servicePackageOfferingId);

const serviceCallRepository = Salesforce.getRepository(ServiceCall);
serviceCall = await serviceCallRepository.save(serviceCall);
```

And the unit test something like this:

```js
const servicePackagesOfferingRepository = new Repository(ServicePackageOffering);
const servicePackagesOfferingRepositoryMock = sandbox.mock(servicePackagesOfferingRepository);

servicePackagesOfferingRepositoryMock
.expects('findOneById')
.withArgs(inputModel.servicePackageOfferingId)
.resolves({});

sandbox
.mock(Salesforce)
.expects('getRepository')
.withArgs(ServicePackageOffering)
.returns(servicePackagesOfferingRepository);

const serviceCallRepository = new Repository(ServiceCall);
const serviceCallRepositoryMock = sandbox.mock(serviceCallRepository);

serviceCallRepositoryMock
.expects('save')
.once();

sandbox
.mock(Salesforce)
.expects('getRepository')
.withExactArgs(ServiceCall)
.returns(serviceCallRepository);
```

But I get this error:

```html
TypeError: Attempted to wrap getRepository which is already wrapped
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to do it:

```js
const SalesforceMock = sandbox.mock(Salesforce);
SalesforceMock.expects('getRepository')
    .twice()
    .onFirstCall()
    .returns(serviceCallRepository)
    .onSecondCall()
    .returns(clientRepository);
```